# Autohotkey - Send key when clicked at certain position on the screen

Tags: autohotkey

I am attempting to write AutoHotkey code that results in sending the Space key when the Left Mouse Button is clicked at some position in the screen (ranges shown below). If the mouse is clicked outside the range, it should result in default behavior. The code below is not working. Example, if I click the Application's Close button whose ypos is less than 170, nothing happens. Request help/inputs. Thanks.

```
 #IfWinActive ahk_class IrfanView
        LButton::
        MouseGetPos,xpos, ypos 
        If (ypos >170 and ypos <570)
        {
        Msgbox %ypos%
        Send, {Space}
        }
        #IfWinActive
        Return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it.

Since, you are handling the left mouse click, nothing further will happen mouse-wise.

So you have to re-issue the click event like this:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IrfanView
LButton::
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos 
If (ypos >170 and ypos <570) {
  Msgbox %ypos%
  Send, {Space}
}
Else {
  Click  
}
Return
```

Also note I removed your second `#ifWinActive`

That shouldn't happen before the return statement.

If you are only adding hotkeys for IrfanView, then that statement won't be necessary at all. If, like me, you are trapping keys for different windows/programs all in one big script, then follow a pattern like this

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class CabinetWClass    ;Windows Explorer
   ...keydefs here...

#IfWinActiveahk_class XLMAIN            ;Excel
   ...keydefs here...

#IfWinActive ahk_exe OUTLOOK.exe        ;Outlook
   ...keydefs here...

#IfWinActive                            ;Keys that work anywhere
   ...all other keydefs here...
```